# Please can you explain what this function does?

Tags: c

Please can someone explain what this function does? And is it possible to code it more efficiently?
I don't understand, especially, the `if` test.

What I can see: it is loading only numbers from a text file and those numbers are being stored to a pointer on the array

```
void LoadNumbers(int*pNumberArray,FILE*textFile) //---F7-
{
    int i = 0;
    while (fscanf(textFile,"%d", &pNumberArray[i]) != EOF)
          {
          if (fscanf(textFile,"%*[^-+0-9]", &pNumberArray[i]) == EOF) break;
          else if (pNumberArray[i] != 0 ){++i; pNumberArray[i] = '\0';
          }    
}
```

Comment: What is stored in `C0`?

Comment: 0 zero sorry i fixed that

Comment: zmocho, what would you like to happen if input text is non-numeric and `fscanf(textFile,"%d", &pNumberArray[i])` returns 0?

Comment: There is no reliable way for the calling function to tell how many records were loaded in the array. (The code messes around with keeping a zero at the end, but if a zero is read, chaos ensues — or any further data is ignored).  There is no way for the function shown to know whether it is safe to store the data — it is not told how big the array is.  The test for `!= EOF` is faulty; it should probably be `== 1` — though there are more elaborate possibilities. Each of those is a serious problem.  You should find a source of better code than wherever it was this junk came from.

Comment: Since `if (fscanf(textFile,"%*[^-+0-9]", &pNumberArray[i]) == EOF) break;` does not assign to anything (the `*` suppresses any assignment), the argument `&pNumberArray[i]` should not be passed to [`fscanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html).

Answer (score 1):

`LoadNumbers()` zero or more integers from `textFile` into `pNumberArray`.  0 values are skipped but a trailing zero is added to signify end of array.  The input file consist of an integer optionally followed by something that is not +, - or a digit.

@ikegami pointed out that you should pass in the size of the array to avoid overflowing `pNumberArray`.  Combine the two `scanf()` calls, add error handling, and just deal with the sentinel after the loop.  (Not fixed) The function could alternatively return how many values are read (`i`) instead of using the 0 sentinel.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void LoadNumbers(size_t n, int pNumberArray[n], FILE *textFile) {
    if(!n) return;
    size_t i = 0;
    while(i + 1 < n) {
        int rv = fscanf(textFile,"%d%*[^0-9+-]", &pNumberArray[i]);
        if(rv == EOF) break;
        if(rv != 1) break; // error: no number found
        if(pNumberArray[i]) i++;
    }
    pNumberArray[i] = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("1.txt", "r");
    if(!f) {
        printf("fopen failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int a[100];
    LoadNumbers(sizeof a / sizeof *a, a, f);
    for(int i = 0; a[i]; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

With the example 1.txt input file:

```
0 a
1 b
0 charlie charlie
2 d
3 echo
4 f
0 golf
```

Both the original and the revised function returns:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: `!i || !pNumberArray[i-1]` is always true. It's true when `i` is zero, and the only time `i` isn't than zero is if you've added a non-zero value to the array. Which makes sense. You always want to add a terminating zero, so the condition should always be true.

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, I see what you are saying, while we may write a 0 in the loop,  we don't advance `i` so the might as well just write it it unconditional 0 after the loop, which worst case overwrites it. Alternatively `if(!pNumberArray[i]) pNumberArray[i] = 0;`

Comment: No, `if(!pNumberArray[i]) pNumberArray[i] = 0;`  is wrong. You might never have assigned to `pNumberArray[i]`, so that results in UB.

Comment: @ikegami op did not tell us the specific c version, if c11, apparently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior  it's only an issue reading an uninitialized value if it's a declared a register (or trap representation which seems esoteric).  If you declare `register a[LEN]` gcc won't compile the program in particular it says the call to the function itself requires taking the address of `a`.  What am I missing?

Comment: If it *could* have been declared as a register. Not if it did. But seeing as its address was taken, it couldn't have been declared as a register. I guess you're right. It's still UB, cause it might happen to be a trap representation, but x86/x86_64 doesn't have that. So I guess `if(!pNumberArray[i]) pNumberArray[i] = 0;` is fine on that architecture.

Comment: ,%d%*[^-+0-9]", please can u explain me how exactly this format string in fscanf works ? bcs ^ means (Only characters ^not listed between the brackets are accepted) so why does it actually read these characters anyway ?

Comment: %d means read an intt; %*[^0-9+-] means read and throw the result away what doesn't match the 0-9+-.

Comment: Sorry for bothering u :D but why there is * and ^ (and why it doesnt do exactly the opposite cuz ^ means not listed between the brackets are accepted)

Comment: The `*` means ignore whatever it reads.  This is why there is no matching variable.  In summary the total format string means read a int then ignore anything that is not a -, + or a digit (this is loosely an int).  So "1x" will read 1 and ignore the x", "12 +x" will read 12, ignore the space, then in time read the + and probably generate an error as that is not a number but ignore the x.

Comment: "12 12" would read an int, ignore the space, then read the int in the next loop iteration.